# Uploading Images Directly to Cloudinary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload images directly to Cloudinary from my Rails app, since I'm on Heroku and can't use the server as an intermediary. They have support for this using jQuery, but when I follow their directions, I get the following error jquery.fileupload-fp.js:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileupload' of undefined.
$.widget('blueimp.fileupload', $.blueimp.fileupload, {
```

Cloudinary replied with an email saying that I should include the js files in the correct order, but they are all included and in the right order. I asked them again, but they might take a while to get back to me and this is somewhat time sensitive.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share a gist with the relevant part of the html (JS includes and javascript code)? This error usually means jquery.fileupload-fp.js is included before jquery.fileupload.js

Comment: Here's the html.erb that renders the page:
https://gist.github.com/jacyclare/5104388

Comment: The includes in the gist do not contain jquery.fileupload-fp.js which was the source of the error. This probably means there are other includes elsewhere.
Can you please share a gist of the generated html?